# When is UIApplicationMain() called?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When is the function `UIApplicationMain()` called? And where it is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's typically called in `main.m`, within the `main()` function:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

It's defined [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html).

**Example:**

[image]